# Does installing libraries and compiling in a Docker container prevent me from screwing up the libraries on the whole computer?

Tags: docker

I apologize if this does show up elsewhere on StackOverflow. If it is here, I'm not using the correct search terms to find it. I'll gladly take a link to the answer.

I have previously tried to compile ElmerGUI on my Ubuntu 20.04 install, and I was met with an immense number of roadblocks that made life very difficult. I managed to get around some, but installing and compiling the various dependencies inevitably FUBARed other libraries on the computer. Adding VTK and OpenGL support during compilation was absolutely horrid for this. I ultimately ended up reinstalling Ubuntu 20.04 far more times than I'd like to admit.

I want to try again now that I'm on Ubuntu 22 and more of the dependencies actually have the necessary versions available in the Ubuntu repositories. However, I still don't want to screw up my computer again like in the past.

Will trying to compile all of the software in a Docker container make this possible? I have never used/built a Docker container, but my understanding is that Docker containers are very similar to being exceptionally stripped down VMs. This makes me think that they will protect me unless I do something exceptionally stupid. Is this the case?

Comment: Tip: [*Docker Desktop*](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/linux-install/) is an easy way to try using Docker. To quote the doc: Docker Desktop for Linux stores containers and images in an isolated storage location within a VM and offers controls to restrict its resources.

Comment: Docker Desktop is most useful on non-Linux operating systems, where you get a Linux VM with a Linux kernel to run Linux containers.  On a Linux host, you still get the (probably unnecessary) VM.  The filesystem and library isolation you discuss in the question is a core Docker feature, and you'll still get it even if you use the plain Docker engine direcly.